TensorFlow on phone using frontcamera as default
I'm trying to make an application that identifies plant diseases but I have a problem that it uses the phone's front camera instead of the back camera, so I need you guys to help me fix it. I tried facing mode but it's not working , so i really need u help rightnow because i have an exam in next 4 days
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="icon" href="https://glitch.com/favicon.ico" />
  <title>Teachable Machine Image Model</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #webcam-container {
      margin-top: 20px;
      position: relative;
      width: calc(100% - 40px);
      max-width: 500px;
    }
    #webcam-container video {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
    #label-container {
      margin-top: 20px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    #label-container div {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>AI nhận diện sâu bệnh </h1>
  <button type="button" onclick="init()">Bắt đầu sử dụng</button>
  <div id="webcam-container"></div>
  <div id="label-container"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/image@latest/dist/teachablemachine-image.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // the link to your model provided by Teachable Machine export panel
    const URL = "https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/g54K3v2DZ/";

    let model, webcam, labelContainer, maxPredictions;

    async function init() {
      const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
      const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";

      model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
      maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();

      // Get user media constraints for the webcam
      const constraints = {
        video: { facingMode: "environment", width: { ideal: 1080 }, height: { ideal: 1920 } }
      };

      // Set up the webcam with the specified constraints
      webcam = new tmImage.Webcam(500, 500, true); // width, height, flip
      await webcam.setup(constraints);
      await webcam.play();
      window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

      // Append elements to the DOM
      document.getElementById("webcam-container").appendChild(webcam.canvas);
      labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
      for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
        labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
      }
    }

    async function loop() {
      webcam.update();
      await predict();
      window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    async function predict() {
      const prediction = await model.predict(webcam.canvas);
      for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
        const classPrediction =
          prediction[i].className + ": " + prediction[i].probability.toFixed(2);
        labelContainer.childNodes[i].innerHTML = classPrediction;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>


I tried Facing Mode but it's not working , so i really need you help
